# Changes committed in one activity not reflected in another when back button is pressed

Tags: android, view, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have two activities (A) and (B), both extending FragmentActivity. If I change data in (B) and press the back button to get back to (A), those changes are not reflected in this activity.

How do I force activity (A) to retrieve the data again? Or is there a better solution?

Construction of view in activity "(A)":

```
mProjectListPagerAdapter = new ProjectListPagerAdapter ( getSupportFragmentManager () );
mViewPager = ( ViewPager ) findViewById ( R.id.pager );
mViewPager.setAdapter ( mProjectListPagerAdapter );
```

Comment: The above code or description won't tell us where your problem really is and how you want to solve it. You seem to be missing shared state, which can be anything from a simple POJO in memory to `SharedPreferences` to SQLiteDB to Content Provider.

Comment: Basically, if one activity changes data on the SD card, the other activity doesn't know about it. Do I notify the other activity of the change? Do I force the other activity to reload data whenever resumed (how?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Refresh data
    }
```